# what are some optimization tricks to make my code run faster

Tags: c++, optimization, random, stdvector, c++-chrono

i'm moving outside my confront zone and trying to make a random number distribution program while also making sure it is still somewhat uniform.
here is my code

this is the RandomDistribution.h file

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>



static float randy(float low, float high) {
    static  std::random_device rd;
    static  std::mt19937 random(rd());
      std::uniform_real_distribution<float> ran(low, high);
    return ran(random);
}


typedef std::vector<float> Vfloat;
class RandomDistribution
{
public:

    RandomDistribution();
    RandomDistribution(float percent, float contents, int container);
    ~RandomDistribution();
    void setvariables(float percent, float contents, int container);
    Vfloat RunDistribution();
private:
    float divider;
    float _percent;
     int jar_limit;
    float _contents;
    float _maxdistribution;
    Vfloat Jar;
    bool is0;
};
```

this is my RandomDistribution.cpp

```
#include "RandomDistribution.h"

RandomDistribution::RandomDistribution() {

}
RandomDistribution::RandomDistribution(float percent, float contents, int containers):_contents(contents),jar_limit(containers)
{
    Jar.resize(containers);
    if (percent < 0)
        _percent = 0;

    else {
        _percent = percent;
    }
    divider = jar_limit * percent;
    is0 = false;
}


RandomDistribution::~RandomDistribution()
{
}
void RandomDistribution::setvariables(float percent, float contents, int container) {
    if (jar_limit != container)
        Jar.resize(container);

    _contents = contents;
    jar_limit = container;
    is0 = false;


    if (percent < 0)
        _percent = 0;

    else {
        _percent = percent;
    }
    divider = jar_limit * percent;
}


Vfloat RandomDistribution::RunDistribution() {

    for (int i = 0; i < jar_limit; i++) {

        if (!is0) {
            if (i + 1 >= jar_limit || _contents < 2) {
                Jar[i] = _contents;
                _contents -= Jar[i];
                is0 = true;
            }

            if (!_percent <= 0) {//making sure it does not get the hole container at once
                _maxdistribution = (_contents / (divider)) * (i + 1);
            }
            else {
                _maxdistribution = _contents;
            }

            Jar[i] = randy(0, _maxdistribution);

            if (Jar[i] < 1) {
                Jar[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }

            _contents -= Jar[i];
        }
        else {
            Jar[0];
        }
        //mixing Jar so it is randomly spaced out instead all at the top
        int swapper = randy(0, i);
        float hold = Jar[i];
        Jar[i] = Jar[swapper];
        Jar[swapper] = hold;

    }

    return Jar;
}
```

source code

```
int main(){
    RandomDistribution distribution[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         distribution[i] = {RandomDistribution(1.0f, 5000.0f, 2000) };
    }


    Vfloat k;
    k.resize(200);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        auto t3 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

        for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) {

            k = distribution[b].RunDistribution();
            distribution[b].setvariables(1.0f, 5000.0f, 2000);

        }

        auto t4 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto time_span = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t4 - t3);
        cout << time_span.count() << " seconds\n";

    }
}
```

what prints out is usually between 1 to 2 seconds for each cycle. i want to bring it down to a tenth of a second if possible cause this is gonna be only one step of the process to completion and i want to run it alot more then 100 times. what can i do to speed this up, any trick or something i'm just missing here.
here is a sample of the time stamps

4.71113 seconds

1.35444 seconds

1.45008 seconds

1.74961 seconds

2.59192 seconds

2.76171 seconds

1.90149 seconds

2.2822 seconds

2.36768 seconds

2.61969 seconds

Comment: If you post this on Code Review, which you are welcome to do, please make sure to use a descriptive title about what the code does, such as "Random number distribution program".

Comment: You are compiling with optimizations / in release mode, right?

Comment: Why not just use [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and [friends](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomNumberDistribution) ?

Comment: [I am not getting the results you're getting](https://www.ideone.com/ZF6wRD).  The same thing [if I use Visual C++](http://rextester.com/YIHQY48657).  Are you building your application with optimizations turned on?

Comment: Also, please explain what you're trying to do here: `if (!_percent <= 0)`.  What exactly does that comparison mean?  Whatever it is, I am sure there are more coherent ways of expressing what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Y.mada If you're using Visual Studio, it makes no sense to use "debug" mode and attempt to optimize it.  The debug runtime uses checked iterators and other debug features that slow down the program, and it has nothing to do with the algorithm you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Cheinan Marks has some benchmarks and performance tips related to random generators & friends in his cppcon 2016 talk [I Just Wanted a Random Integer!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_QO1nm7uJs) He mentions some fast generators as well IIRC. I'd start there.